Remember window position and size with Master PDF Editor
I use Ubuntu 24.04 and Master PDF Editor (version 5.9.85). I want the PDF reader to remember window size and position, just like Nautilus or Chrome does. At the moment, only the maximized window is remembered, but I want to work with a minimized window which I position manually at my convenience. The app keeps repositioning the window somewhere else upon closing. I tried with Okular, too, and it does the same. Very frustrating
